# Isolating a nested sibling tag using XPATH

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to retreive `"prace.avizo.cz"` and `"onlineprodej.cz"` from the following html. I've tried several different variations to isolate that one url but none have been successful.

I'm trying to get it via an `importXML` function in a googledoc. Some of the paths I've tried are:

```
=importXML(B2,"//article[@class='genericlist component leadingReferers']//ul/li[1]")

=importXML(B2,"//ul[@class='sites items']//li[1]")

=importXML(B2,"//li[@class='item']//div//a")
```

These either don't work or return extra irrelevant data. I'm only looking for the data within this specific article *class* (`genericlist component leadingReferers`).

Any help is appreciated.

```
<article class="genericlist component leadingReferers">

<h2 class="title">
    Top Publishers
    <i class="tooltip sprite icon_tip_idle" title="&amp;lt;h1&amp;gt;Leading paid referring sites&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;Leading publishers referring advertising traffic to Cz.indeed.com"></i>
</h2>
<ul class="sites items">
        <li class="item ">
                <div class="text" title="prace.avizo.cz" data-sitename="prace.avizo.cz">
                    <a class="link" href="/website/prace.avizo.cz" data-tipsygravity="w" data-shorturl="Prace.avizo.cz">
                            <img class="icon lazy-icon lazy"  data-original="http://images2.similargroup.com/image?url=prace.avizo.cz&amp;t=2&amp;s=1&amp;h=11351681863127555753" src="/images/lazy.png"/>
                            <noscript>
                                <img class="icon" src="http://images2.similargroup.com/image?url=prace.avizo.cz&amp;t=2&amp;s=1&amp;h=11351681863127555753"/>
                            </noscript>

                        Prace.avizo.cz
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <div class="progress-value percentage per1" style="width: 62.91%"></div>
                </div>

        </li>
        <li class="item ">
                <div class="text" title="onlineprodej.cz" data-sitename="onlineprodej.cz">
                    <a class="link" href="/website/onlineprodej.cz" data-tipsygravity="w" data-shorturl="Onlineprodej.cz">
                            <img class="icon lazy-icon lazy"  data-original="http://images2.similargroup.com/image?url=onlineprodej.cz&amp;t=2&amp;s=1&amp;h=14252445317786093368" src="/images/lazy.png"/>
                            <noscript>
                                <img class="icon" src="http://images2.similargroup.com/image?url=onlineprodej.cz&amp;t=2&amp;s=1&amp;h=14252445317786093368"/>
                            </noscript>

                        Onlineprodej.cz
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <div class="progress-value percentage per1" style="width: 50.88%"></div>
                </div>
        </li>
....
```

Comment: What do you actually intend to select? The text? The full node? That text `prace.avizo.cz` is avaliable in several places. Where would you want to get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression will give you the last *text node* inside the `<a>` of the *first* item in the article:

```
//article[@class='genericlist component leadingReferers']//li[1]//a/text()[last()]
```

which is the one that contains the text `Prace.avizo.cz` (surrounded by spaces, tabs and newlines). If you wish to *trim* those extra spaces, you can pass that expression as the argument to the XPath function `normalize-space()`:

```
normalize-space( //article[@class='genericlist component leadingReferers']//li[1]//a/text()[last()] )
```

You can select the second article in a similar manner (same expression, using `li[2]`):

```
//article[@class='genericlist component leadingReferers']//li[2]//a/text()[last()]
```

If you want to retrieve a *collection* containing all text nodes (which you can manupulate outside of XPath) you can use:

```
//article[@class='genericlist component leadingReferers']//li//a/text()[last()]
```

which will return a list containing all text nodes (two, in your example). In this case, you will have to use your host language to extract them (probably in a for-each loop).